# After x login attempts failed

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is to get the counter to work for x failed logins. 
My columns in MySQL are: id, username, password, attempts & adress!

```
if ($result[0]['total'] == true)
{

    $_SESSION['userLogin'] = $result[0]['total'];
    $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = $login;
    header('location: index.php?id=home');
    $db->query("UPDATE authenticate SET attempts=0, adress='$ip' WHERE username='$login'");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $rs = mysql_query('SELECT id,username,password,attempts,address FROM authenticate WHERE username = '.$username.'');
    $num = mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if ($row['attempts'] > 3) {
        // Redirect to captcha
        header('location: captcha.php');
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        if ($row['address'] != $ip) {
        // New ip adress, reset failed logins
        $failed_logins = 0;
        } else {
        // Increment failed logins
        $failed_logins = $row['attempts']+1;
        }
        mysql_query('UPDATE authenticate SET attempts = '.$failed_logins.',address = '.$ip.' WHERE id = '.$row['id'].' ');
    }
header('location: index.php');
exit;
}
```

Comment: This calls for basic step-by-step debugging first. What goes wrong where?

Comment: Don't you need to `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)` first?

Comment: I know of printr, die and <pre> but how should I use it here? It seems like nothing goes wrong, it can or fail login and does it like it supposed to. But the counter does not increase. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is not need for a database counter, Instead create a session called attempts and increment that instead. Using a database will be slower and less efficient than just using a session and incrementing that :) This should solve your problem and use less coding. Here is the code using my idea and it should also work:

```
//Checks if the user is logged in
if ($result[0]['total'] == true){
    //Sets the users login
    $_SESSION['userLogin'] = $result[0]['total'];
    //Sets the loggedin variable
    $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = $login;
    //Resets the attempts
    $_SESSION['attempts'] = 0;
    //Redirects to index.php?id=home
    header('location: index.php?id=home');
    exit;
}else{
    //Checks if the attempts are greater than three
    if ($_SESSION['attempts'] > 3) {
        // Redirect to captcha
        header('location: captcha.php');
    } else {
        //Increments the session variable
        $_SESSION['attempts'] = $_SESSION['attempts'] + 1;
        //Goes back to the index page
         header('location: index.php');
         exit;
    }
}
exit;
```

Comment: Your first `header()` should be after the db query (since the redirect _might_ occur before the query call gets seen) and your second instance of `header()` needs an exit, otherwise two location headers might be sent.

Comment: Thanks, +1. Just thought - if an attacker turns off their cookies, or sends you a random one every time, then this approach would need extra work. Maybe ensure that the user is accepting cookies, and that the cookie they've presented is recognised by your app?

Comment: How would that work? I Think if he uses https he could use secure cookies so that they couldn't be deleted?

Comment: Why exactly can't you use sessions?

Comment: I think i can, but it would be neat with a members table. Btw the session example you provided didnt work. Any help to debug?

Comment: I changed it but how exactly did it not work. Did it display an error? Did it not work when you tried three time? Are you using session_start()?

Comment: One way of ensuring that a cookie really originates from your server is to encrypt the IP plus a known secret, which can be checked when it is presented (by decrypting it). However, I guess this wouldn't help, since an attacker could then clear their cookie and get a new one on each attempt. I think a database of IPs versus attempts is necessary here - allowing for a good number of attempts to take into account people legitimately sharing proxy server addresses.

Comment: It did not (blank page). I pass start_session() from libs/config.php and it works.

Comment: That's great. You need to remember to start sessions before using them. Can you please give a green tick if this has been resolved!

Comment: No not yet I'm still stuck on were and how I should count the attempts. But I found some resources, so I will still try with the database.